# Insert value into array element in an array element and return array length

Tags: arrays, mongodb

I would like to add a value to an a field which lies within an array element, I would also like the amount of elements in the array to be returned and also that only one value is allowed to be input. below is the data:

```
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("56bb59beb32fa53064f51e3f"),
    "title" : "okok",
    "views" : 1,
    "messages" : [
        {
            "authorId" : ObjectId("56bb599e8f308f1664c93011"),
            "upvotes" : [], // <--- want to push a value here
            "created" : ISODate("2016-02-10T15:39:42.006Z"),
            "updated" : ISODate("2016-02-10T15:39:42.006Z"),
            "message" : "okok"
        },
        {
            "authorId" : ObjectId("56bb599e8f308f1664c93010"),
            "upvotes" : [], // <--- insert into here plz
            "created" : ISODate("2016-02-10T15:39:47.170Z"),
            "updated" : ISODate("2016-02-10T15:39:47.170Z"),
            "message" : "uhuhuh"
        },
        {
            "authorId" : ObjectId("56bb599e8f308f1664c93011"),
            "upvotes" : [],
            "created" : ISODate("2016-02-10T15:40:01.772Z"),
            "updated" : ISODate("2016-02-10T15:40:01.772Z"),
            "message" : "åpåpå"
        },
        {
            "authorId" : ObjectId("56bb599e8f308f1664c93010"),
            "upvotes" : [],
            "created" : ISODate("2016-02-10T15:40:04.889Z"),
            "updated" : ISODate("2016-02-10T15:40:04.889Z"),
            "message" : "påpåpå<br /><br />påå"
        },
        {
            "authorId" : ObjectId("56bb599e8f308f1664c93010"),
            "upvotes" : [],
            "created" : ISODate("2016-02-11T12:36:26.006Z"),
            "updated" : ISODate("2016-02-11T12:36:26.006Z"),
            "message" : "testt"
        },
        {
            "authorId" : ObjectId("56bb599e8f308f1664c93013"),
            "upvotes" : [],
            "created" : ISODate("2016-02-11T12:36:31.514Z"),
            "updated" : ISODate("2016-02-11T12:36:31.514Z"),
            "message" : "tetetet"
        }
    ]
}
```

I have the document `_id` and the array element `created` field to locate the element in the array.

I tried the following:

```
}  
    $match: {
        _id: retard.ObjectId(data.id),
        'messages.created': data.created
    }
}, {
    $group: {
        'messages.$.upvotes': {
            $addToSet: 'myTestValueToInsert'
        }
    }
}, {
    $project: {
        numUpvotes: {
            $size: '$upvotes'
        }
    }
}, {
    multi: false
}
```

However getting an error. I've been reading the aggregation documentation but the examples are slightly lacking!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The [`aggregation`](https://docs.mongodb.org/manual/aggregation/#aggregation) framework is not intended to and cannot be used to insert or update documents([`this`](https://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/out/#pipe._S_out) is an extended capability and not an exception), rather, it *can* process data records and return computed results.

You could use the [`update`](https://docs.mongodb.org/v3.0/reference/method/db.collection.update/#db-collection-update) query to update matching sub document:

```
var myTestValueToInsert = 1;
db.t.update({
             "_id":retard.ObjectId(data.id),
             "messages.created":data.created
            },
            {
              "$addToSet":{"messages.$.upvotes":myTestValueToInsert}
            })
```

Then, to retrieve the size of the modified array, you could aggregate it as below:

```
db.t.aggregate([
{$match:{"_id":retard.ObjectId(data.id)}},
{$unwind:"$messages"},
{$match:{"messages.created":data.created}},
{$project:{"size":{$size:"$messages.upvotes"},"_id":0}}
])
```

If you are using the shell, there is a nice [`wrapper`](https://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/method/db.collection.findAndModify/) to update and get the updated document, but you would need to get the size of the array inside the document in the client side:

```
db.t.findAndModify({
  "query":{"_id":retard.ObjectId(data.id),"messages.created":data.created},
  "update":{$addToSet:{"messages.$.upvotes":myTestValueToInsert}},
  "new":true
})
```

Comment: ***Wow +1***. The first paragraph really opened my eyes now, i never realized that aggregation could be used to process data. I always thought of aggregation as an advanced query (in which you can update records/insert). After re-reading the documentation it's starting to make more sense. Wish your paragraph was in the official mongodb docs, would of saved me time and headaches!